# Randomly select an array element

Tags: vb.net

So I'm trying to select a random element and then save said element, not quite knowing as to how I would go about doing this. The first thing that came to mind, although messy to write was:

```
Rnd(griddata(1), griddata(2), griddata(...))
```

I did receive an error however from this:

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Rnd' accepts this
>   number of arguments.

The plan is to store whatever random element it chooses as memory as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    Dim myArray() As Integer = {1, 10, 12, 11, 44, 23, 2, 1, 5, 6, 2, 7}
    Dim rnd As New Random
    Dim randomArrayElement = myArray(rnd.Next(0, myArray.Length - 1))
```

Or even you can try the same from a string also

```
    Dim chars = "0123456789"
    Dim random = New Random()
    Dim result = New String(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 1).[Select](Function(s) s(randomOtp.[Next](s.Length))).ToArray())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim rnd = new Random()
...
Dim randomIndex = rnd.Next(0, griddata.Length)
Dim randomValue = griddata(randomIndex)
```

This is assuming that your array is 0-based (as .NET arrays usually are).